# ruby on rails params not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im a rails (and ruby) newbie and struggling with an a scaffolded controller that i was trying to tweak more to my configurations- the record is being saved but the fields in the db are null- here is the result of the development.log

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 10:36:55 +0000
  Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mizap5163W5RbRrHiWdepYZDgrsaflhJPWaVhdHlaOA=", "event"=>{"title"=>"bla de bla", "details"=>"bla de bla", "ticket_info"=>"bla de bla", "when(1i)"=>"2011", "when(2i)"=>"12", "when(3i)"=>"12", "when(4i)"=>"10", "when(5i)"=>"34", "ends(1i)"=>"2011", "ends(2i)"=>"12", "ends(3i)"=>"12", "ends(4i)"=>"10", "ends(5i)"=>"34"}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `events` (`created_at`, `details`, `ends`, `image_url`, `location`, `organiser_id`, `ticket_info`, `title`, `updated_at`, `when`) VALUES ('2011-12-12 10:36:55', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-12-12 10:36:55', NULL)[0m
  [1m[35m (45.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events/11
Completed 302 Found in 67ms
```

the form and the controller are pretty basic so i do not know where i have gone wrong.

controller methods-

```
# GET /Events/new
  # GET /Events/new.json
  def new
    @Event = Event.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @Event }
    end
  end

  # GET /Events/1/edit  
  def edit
    @Event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /Events
  # POST /Events.json
  def create
    @Event = Event.new(params[:Event])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @Event.save

        format.html { redirect_to @Event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @Event, status: :created, location: @Event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @Event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And the form (probably very basic mistakes)

```
<%= form_for(@Event) do |f| %>

  <% if @Event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@Event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @Event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :details %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :details %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ticket_info %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :ticket_info %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :when %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :when %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ends %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :ends %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the model- (i added in the attr_accessible tags thinking it owuld make a difference)

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :Details, :image_url, :organiser_id, :ticket_info, :when, :ends, :location
end
```

you can see from the log that the sql query is not inserting a row with any data but the params are they

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
def create
    @Event = Event.new(params[:Event])
    ....
end
```

It should be:

```
def create
    @Event = Event.new(params[:event])
    ....
end
```

hf...

// And also you should use downcase in cvariable Names. Uppercase should only be used for Constants like the ClassName!

Comment: is this a convention- even if the variable in form_for is uppercase the params will be lowercase? (just for future)

Comment: Yes thats right! You should folow the convention because it helps you to accomplish applications that other coders could work with! Also its helpfull for partials that are application wide and not only for one model!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ruby naming conventions [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7).

It is advised to always use lowercase instance variables! So use `@event` instead of `@Event`.

So following rails guidelines (and your scaffold would have looked the same), your controller `create` method should look like:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Note that only class-names, module-names and constants are ever capitalized. Symbols are always lower-cased by convention.

Hope this helps.